# Default parameter is still empty string

Tags: c#, .net-4.8

I have a class that inherits from Interface with this definition

```
public interface IModel
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> AddValuePairs(string prefix = "");
    }
```

All is fine but when I call the method and pass a prefix it still sees it as empty.

```
public sealed class AuthURLInputModel : IModel 
    {
        public string Username {get;set;}
        public string Idnumber {get;set;}

        public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> AddValuePairs(string prefix="user")
        {
            var pre = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? prefix : string.Empty;
            var keyValuePairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(ModelHelper.GetPrefixedName("username", prefix), Username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(ModelHelper.GetPrefixedName("idnumber", prefix), Idnumber)
            };
            return keyValuePairs;
        }

    }
```

Calls to

> AddValuePairs(string prefix = "user[0]")

still sees prefix as empty string instead of

> "user[0]"

that was passed in.

```
protected TModel Post<TModel, TInputModel>(string funcName, TInputModel inputModel)
            where TInputModel : IModel
{
  var inputs = inputModel.AddValuePairs();
}
```

Where  `TInputModel` is `AuthURLInputModel`
Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by "call the class"? It's a method, not a class, and the code you've used isn't valid for calling a method anyway - it's as if you've provided another *declaration*, but without explaining in what way you've done so. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: (I strongly suspect the problem is that you're changing the default in an implementation, but then still using an interface-typed variable at compile-time to call the method, but at the moment the question is too unclear for me to be sure.  Whereas if we had a complete example, it would be easy to answer...)

Comment: (Note that when constructing a minimal example, I'd make it a simple void method. No need for that complex return type, when the returned value isn't relevant to the question.)

Comment: noted, producing a simple call to it

Comment: This is far from a minimal example. A lot of it is entirely irrelevant. Here's a genuine [mcve]: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/b8a8746e79071da9232d20a885f4153f

Comment: @PoulBak: It really doesn't matter.  The compiler processes the generic function body only once, before it knows the actual type of any type argument.

Comment: @PoulBak, it is

Answer (score 3):

The default value for optional parameters is used at *compile-time*, based on the compile-time type of the expression of the target of the method call. In this case, the compile-time type is `TInputModel`, but the compiler only "knows" about the declaration in the interface, so that's how it determines which value to use by default.

Here's a simpler, complete example:

```cs
using System;

public interface IFoo
{
    void M(int x = 0);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void M(int x = 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        IFoo foo2 = foo1;

        // Prints 10, because the compiler knows
        // about the declaration of Foo.M
        foo1.M();
        // Prints 0, because the compiler only
        // knows about the declaration of IFoo.M
        foo2.M();
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise you *not* to change the default value in interface-implementing (or base-class-overriding) methods. It causes confusion - as your question demonstrates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the direction. that means I need to new it up?

Comment: @Tonto: I honestly don't know what you're considering. Creating a new instance won't give the compiler any more information. But again, I'd *strongly* advise you to avoid trying to use the default values of optional parameters as if they were polymorphic. They're not.

Comment: @Tonto: Perhaps you should use just a default value of `null` in the interface, and then let each implementation treat that in whatever way it sees fit.

Comment: That was the whole idea, let each implementation of the interface treat it as they see fit. That interface is implemented in quite a number of classes with each implementation a little different

Comment: @Tonto: Right, so let them all use the same compile-time default value, but *handle* that default value differently. The *implementation* is polymorphic, but the compile-time default value isn't.